# How to check dependency on nominal variables?

Tags: categorical-data, independence

I have data that map one real (float) and several nominal arguments to one real value:

```
y = f(r, n1, n2, n3, n4)
```

If I check dependency of `y` on `r` (r is my real-valued variable), I see that `y` depends linearly on `r` with a lot of noise on top of this dependency.

Now I want to check if there is any dependency of `y` on nominal variables: n1, n2, n3, n4. I also would like to know what nominal variable has the largest influence on `y`. So, my question is: **What methods can I used to do that?**

Comment: Can you show us the data (using graphs)?

Comment: @Roman Luštrik, I am not sure what graph you need. How should I build it? The only graph that I have is `y` as function of `x` (it ignores values of other variables). It looks like `y` linearly depends on `x` with a lot of noise. The second problem, I think I am not allowed to post the data on line, since it is property of the company that I am working on.

Answer (score 1):

Regression with dummy variables for the levels of the nominal variables (factors) would probably be an obvious first thought, but as @RomanLuštrik points out the first thing to do is plot the data.

An example plot with one linear variable and one factor:

[image]

(That data is from [this page](http://www.agr.kuleuven.ac.be/vakken/statisticsbyR/ANOVAbyRr/ANCOVAinR.htm))

There are various other plots that can be done.

Here's another example:

[image]

(Same data, somewhat different kind of plot)

Here is a document that discusses some other plots for this kind of data (like boxplots).

Comment: thank you for the answer. Unfortunately, I do not understand the data. There are four columns which of them is function and which are arguments. If I assume that the last (or fist) columns is the function than I have one real-valued argument and two (not one as you say) nominal-valued variables (or factors). I also do not understand the first plot. It looks like there are four plots. Why four? And what is x and what is y. What is "priorlmp" and what is "Improv"?

Comment: Improv is the $y$, PriorImp is the $x$. RDExp is a factor (nominal). The other one is actually a replicate number but I have treated it kind of like it was a factor in the second plot. As for what the data measure, I have no clue. The fourth plot (lower right) combines the two plots on the left. Don't worry about it - just try to comprehend the general idea of doing a separate y vs x for each level of a factor (that's called a coplot). The second plot is called an interaction plot. If you gave some sample data, someone might be able to generate one for you.